# How to select an image and add it to a list in dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-image-picker

There is a part in my app that users can pick multiple images from their device. I use image_picker package to do this.After selecting images,they are listed and showed to the user.By tapping on each image, user can edit (like putting text on the image) and save it to the gallery.Here the problem begins.I want to replace the edited image with the original image in the list which all selected images are in it and show them the new edited image.
As you probably know,the type of the list that the selected images are stored in it is `XFile`.
I don't know how to do this automatically after saving the image.Any suggestion can be helpful.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put some code ! What you've tried??